# Faster still image capture with AVFoundation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, avfoundation

I use some code to capture still images from the camera. With my iPad2, it grabs 30 frames per second without any trouble, but with the iPhone4 only around 4 fps before the imagebuffer gets full. Is there any way to make it faster, I need at least 15 fps. I just save the images in an array, so maybe I just have to increase the imagesamplebuffer?

```
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {
     NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];

     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
     [arrCaptures addObject:image];
     [image release];
 }];
```

Comment: I'm now trying the code here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html which work in 15 fps in 30 seconds before it crashes. And I had to remove the line [self setSession:session]; for some reason I don't know.